# ncurses - how the TINFO_SETUP_TERM works?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, ncurses

I trying to understand working of ncurses as we called `initscr()` for ncurses to init screen

function defined in file ncurses lib_initscr.c and tries to open terminal through newterm i.e. lib_newterm.c file and it uses:

```
if ( TINFO_SETUP_TERM(&new_term, name,fileno(_ofp), &errret, FALSE) != ERR) ){
}
```

and when I open the curses.priv.h as:

```
#ifdef USE_TERM_DRIVER
    #define TINFO_SETUP_TERM(tpp, name, fd, err, reuse) \
        _nc_setupterm_ex(tpp, name, fd, err, reuse)
#else

    #define TINFO_SETUP_TERM(tpp, name, fd, err, reuse) \
        _nc_setupterm(name, fd, err, reuse)
#endif
```

and in lib_setup.c the functions are defined as under:

```
#ifdef USE_TERM_DRIVER
    NCURSES_EXPORT(int) _nc_setupterm(
            NCURSES_CONST char *tname, int Filedes, int *errret, bool reuse){
            }
#endif
```

I didn't find where is function `_nc_setupterm_ex()` defined in the source code and how if the `USE_TERM_DRIVER` is not defined then how it link to the `_nc_setupterm();`

Answer (score 1):

`TINFO_SETUP_TERM` is defined in `ncurses/tinfo/lib_setup.c` (line 577 in the ncurses 5.9 source) the macros you show set the name of the function to either `_nc_setupterm` or `_nc_setupterm_ex`.

If `USE_TERM_DRIVER` is defined then `TINFO_SETUP_TERM` is defined as `_nc_setupterm_ex` and `_nc_setupterm` becomes a wrapper for `TINFO_SETUP_TERM` (which is `nc_setupterm_ex`)

If USE_TERM_DRIVER`is not defined then`TINFO_SETUP_TERM`is defined as`_nc_setupterm`and the definition of`_nc_setupterm` you quoted does not get compiled.